# I want to set textfield from separate class

Tags: android

When I use setUI() in onUpgrade in SQLiteOpenHelper, NullPointerException is displayed.
why is this?
I want to display textfield on display from separate class, so if there is other good way, please tell me that. (for example LayoutInflater? but, when I used LayoutInflater, showed nothing.)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

　　　　　　　・
　　　　　　　・
　　　　　　　・

public void setUI(String fileName,String word,String yen,String category){
        TextView categoryText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.category);
        categoryText.setText(category);
        Bitmap image=loadImage(fileName,this);
        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        TextView wordText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.word);
        wordText.setText(word);
        TextView yenText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.yen);
        yenText.setText(yen);
}
```

---

```
private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DB_NAME,null,4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table if not exists "+DB_TABLE+"(id integer primary key autoincrement,image text,word text, yen text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("create table if not exists "+CATEGORY_DB_TABLE+"(id integer primary key autoincrement, category text)");
        db.execSQL("insert into category(category) values('カテゴリー１')");
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from test inner join category on test.id = category.id",null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        MyActivity myActivity=new MyActivity();
        myActivity.setUI(c.getString(1),c.getString(2),c.getString(3),c.getString(5));
    }
```

Comment: `myActivity.setUI()`'s `myActivity` instance is not the activity users(or you) are seeing on display. This is not android problem but basic Java problem. If You are a beginner about Android and Java, take official tour of gettting started for Android. https://developer.android.com/training/index.html these contents have valuable tutorials and techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `myActivity.setUI` immediately after instanting the `MyActivity` class. By the time your `view` would not have been inflated.

Instead you should try to store the required data in the `MyActivity` in some variable and check for its presence in the `onCreate` method after the `setContentView` call and then call your `setUI` method. Also this will be called only if your activity is displayed on the screen.